# ios google map sdk GMSCoreResources.bundle not loaded ios7 xcode5

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xac13c70  (not loaded)

try delete framework & bundle clean re add

try create new project

no solution

Comment: Be advised, iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are currently under NDA. Ask your question on the Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

This Seems like a bug on Google Maps see

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5640

Alex